# Springboot 2.5.6 gives java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds issues

Tags: java, spring-boot

Since migration to `springboot 2.5.6` I have to register our `ObjectMapper` with `JavaTimeModule`. However, I am getting the below error for the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`. How can I fix it?

The input time that we get is something like `2020-07-01T10:00:00.000+0000`

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Error

```
 java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: OffsetSeconds
```

Our Serialization

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` does not support timezones by definition.  Therefore it doesn't support OffsetSeconds.

You should leave off the `+0000` in the input and the `Z` in the format.  Alternatively, use `ZonedDateTime` instead.

I don't know which version of Spring Boot you were using before, but maybe it was using an older version of Jackson which used JSR10Module.

From the JavaTimeModule docs:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html

> Note that as of 2.6, this module does NOT support auto-registration, because of existence of legacy version, JSR310Module. Legacy version has the same functionality, but slightly different default configuration: see JSR310Module for details.

From the JSR310Module docs:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html

> Old JSR310Module defaults to serialization WITH Timezone Ids (to support round-trippability of values when using JSR-310 types and Jackson)

Comment: How did it work in the previous versions of Spring boot then? I had the same setting.. Only after I migrated to 2.5.6 version and had to update the `ObjectMapper` these problems started

Comment: @user3310115 According to the info in the question, you weren't using JavaTimeModule, what were you using instead?  What guide did you follow that said you had to update the ObjectMapper?  Can you show the exact changes you made?

Comment: @user3310115 I think you were using JSR310Module, answer updated.

Comment: Moving to ZonedDateTime fixed the issue